# C++ overloading * for polynomial multiplication

Tags: c++, polynomial-math

So I have been developing a polynomial class where a user inputs: 1x^0 + 2x^1 + 3x^2... and 1,2,3 (the coefficients) are stored in an int array

My overloaded + and - functions work, however, * doesnt work. No matter the input, it always shows -842150450
when is should be (5x^0 + x^1) * (-3x^0 + x^1) = **-15x^0 + 2x^1 + 1x^2**
 or (x+5)(x-3) = x^2 +2x - 15

I'm using the overloaded * function like : `Polynomial multiply = one * two;`
Im guessing the problem is strtol(p, &endptr, 10) since it uses a long int, however, adding and subtracting works perfectly

My constructor

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(char *s)
{
    char *string;
    string = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
    int length = strlen(string);
    strcpy(string, s);

    char *copy;
    copy = new char [length];
    strcpy(copy, string);

    char *p = strtok(string, "  +-");
    counter = 0;
    while (p) 
    {
        p = strtok(NULL, "  +-");
        counter++;
    }

    coefficient = new int[counter];

    p = strtok(copy, "  +");
    int a = 0;
    while (p)
    {
        long int coeff;
        char *endptr;
        coeff = strtol(p, &endptr, 10); //stops at first non number
        if (*p == 'x')
           coeff = 1;

        coefficient[a] = coeff;
        p = strtok(NULL, "  +");
        a++;
    }
}
```

and the overloaded * function

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator * (const Polynomial &right)
{
    Polynomial temp;

    //make coefficient array
    int count = (counter + right.counter) - 1;
    temp.counter = count;
    temp.coefficient = new int [count];
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < right.counter; j++)
            temp.coefficient[i+j] += coefficient[i] * right.coefficient[j];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And heres my entire code: http://pastie.org/721143

Comment: My overloaded + and - functions work, however, the overloaded * doesnt work. No matter the input, it always shows -842150450

Comment: I downloaded your code from pastie.org, compiled it with g++ 4.4.1 and it runs just fine.  Needs some error checking.

Comment: Obvious, but are you actually multiplying by a Polynomial and not a string or something else?

Comment: My C is admittedly rusty, but isn't he allocating his return value on the stack with the way it's written, and then trying to return it ... which may or may not work depending on the test code?

Comment: swilden: I used g++ previously (dont know which version) but I have to compile this for windows so I'm using visual c++ express 2008

Comment: and it worked perfectly using g++ but im getting -842150450 no matter what my input is using visual c++

Comment: @Donnie, it's perfectly fine to return values allocated on stack (they will simply be copied). It's not fine to return a _reference_ or _pointer_ to a local variable, but that doesn't happen here.

Comment: 1) Why are you taking the length of `string` before there is anything _in_ `string` ? 2) You should store the result of `strlen()` in a `size_t` rather than a signed variable like `int`.

Comment: @Pavel: Ah, thank you.  A difference that I wasn't thinking of, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't appear to initialise the `temp.coefficient[i+j]` to zero in your `operator * ()`.

```
temp.coefficient = new int [count];
std::memset (temp.coefficient, 0, count * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: An easier way to do this in one statement is `new int[count]()`, which will default-initialize every element.

Comment: Please look at my answer, your code is not "safe" to work everywhere even with this fix.

Comment: @Raptrex, it's because `new int[N]` does not fill the array with zeroes. All elements of the array have indeterminate initial values. `memset` will set them all to `0`, or you can use `new int[N](0) or new int[N]()` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Convert -842150450 to hex to find back one of the [magic values](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) used in the CRT in the debug build.  That helps finding the bug in your code:

```
    temp.coefficient = new int [count];
    // Must initialize the memory
    for (int ix = 0; ix < count; ++ix) temp.coefficient[ix] = 0;
```

There are plenty other bugz btw, good luck fixing them.

Comment: That's a pretty inefficient way to initialize an array. Use a `memset` instead, or an explicit initializer in `new[]`.

Comment: Take a look at the generated code for this loop in the Release build.

Comment: You should still use `memset`, `std::fill`, or best of all `new[]()`. Those functions are standard and easier to read than a hand-written loop.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
temp.coefficient = new int [count];
```

give you an array of zeroes?

Otherwise in your for loop you're adding stuff to garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
temp.coefficient = new int [count];
```

by

```
temp.coefficient = new int [count]();
```

in order to zero-initialize the array values.